# Angular Reactive form does not show built-in validator error message

Tags: angular

I was working with angular reactive form validation and I got an unexpected problem. I created a built-in validator to filter out restricted words from a textarea. The code was supposed to identify the restricted words, and if they appear on the textarea, it would mark the textarea as invalid and display an error message on top of the textarea i.e **"Restricted words found: foo, bar"** The textarea has other validations in place such as **required** and **maxLength(400)**, which work fine and display error messages. The problem I'm having only occurs with the custom validator. Although the textarea correctly identifies the restricted words and marks the field as invalid, the error message does not display. What could be the issue? I got no errors from npm or the console.

Here is my component class: **create-session.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ISession, restrictedWords } from '../shared/index';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'create-session.component.html',
    styles: [`
      em { float: right; color: #E05C65; padding-left: 10px; }
      .error input, .error select, .error textarea { background-color: #E3C3C5; }
      .error ::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #999; }
      .error ::-moz-placeholder { color: #999; }
      .error :ms-input-placeholder { color: #999; }
    `]
})

export class CreateSessionComponent implements OnInit {
    newSessionForm:FormGroup
    name:FormControl
    presenter:FormControl
    duration:FormControl
    level:FormControl
    abstract:FormControl

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.name = new FormControl('', Validators.required)
        this.presenter = new FormControl('', Validators.required)
        this.duration = new FormControl('', Validators.required)
        this.level = new FormControl('', Validators.required)
        this.abstract = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(400), restrictedWords(['foo', 'bar'])])

        this.newSessionForm = new FormGroup({
            name: this.name,
            presenter: this.presenter,
            duration: this.duration,
            level: this.level,
            abstract: this.abstract
        })
    }

    saveSession(formValues) {
        let session:ISession = {
            id: undefined,
            name: formValues.name,
            duration: +formValues.duration,
            level: formValues.level,
            presenter: formValues.presenter,
            abstract: formValues.abstract,
            voters: []
        }

        console.log(session)
    }
}
```

Here is my component html: **create-session.component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <h3>Create Session</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <form [formGroup]="newSessionForm" (ngSubmit)="saveSession(newSessionForm.value)" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'error': name.invalid && name.dirty}" >
      <label for="sessionName">Session Name:</label>
      <em *ngIf="name.invalid && name.dirty">Required</em>
      <input formControlName="name" id="sessionName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="session name..." />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'error': presenter.invalid && presenter.dirty}" >
      <label for="eventDate">Presenter:</label>
      <em *ngIf="presenter.invalid && presenter.dirty">Required</em>      
      <input formControlName="presenter" id="presenter" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="presenter..." />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'error': duration.invalid && duration.dirty}" >
      <label for="duration">Duration:</label>
      <em *ngIf="duration.invalid && duration.dirty">Required</em>      
      <select formControlName="duration" class="form-control">
        <option value="">select duration...</option>
        <option value="1">Half Hour</option>
        <option value="2">1 Hour</option>
        <option value="3">Half Day</option>
        <option value="4">Full Day</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'error': level.invalid && level.dirty}" >
      <label for="level">Level:</label>
      <em *ngIf="level.invalid && level.dirty">Required</em>      
      <select formControlName="level" class="form-control">
        <option value="">select level...</option>
        <option value="Beginner">Beginner</option>
        <option value="Intermediate">Intermediate</option>
        <option value="Advanced">Advanced</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'error': abstract.invalid && abstract.dirty}" >
      <label for="abstract">Abstract:</label>
      <em *ngIf="abstract.invalid && abstract.dirty && abstract?.errors.required">Required</em> 
      <em *ngIf="name.invalid && name.dirty && abstract?.errors.maxlength">Cannot exceed 400 characters</em>     
      <em *ngIf="name.invalid && name.dirty && abstract?.errors.restrictedWords">
        Restricted words found: {{abstract.errors.restrictedWords}}
      </em>
      <textarea formControlName="abstract"  id="abstract" rows=3 class="form-control" placeholder="abstract..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="newSessionForm.invalid">Save</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is my custom validator: **restricted-words.validator.ts**

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function restrictedWords(words) {
    return (control: FormControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
        if(!words) return null

        var invalidWords = words
            .map(w => control.value.includes(w) ? w : null) 
                .filter(w => w != null)

        return invalidWords && invalidWords.length > 0 
        ? {'restrictedWords' : invalidWords.join(', ')} 
        : null
    }
}
```

Here's a **github repo** if it helps: https://github.com/AshrafLobo/Angular-Demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a small copy-paste error, you have to replace `name` with `abstract`

```
     <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'error': abstract.invalid && abstract.dirty}" >
      <label for="abstract">Abstract:</label>
      <em *ngIf="abstract.invalid && abstract.dirty && abstract?.errors.required">Required</em> 
      <em *ngIf="abstract.invalid && abstract.dirty && abstract?.errors.maxlength">Cannot exceed 400 characters</em>     
      <em *ngIf="abstract.invalid && abstract.dirty && abstract?.errors.restrictedWords">
        Restricted words found: {{abstract.errors.restrictedWords}}
      </em>
      <textarea formControlName="abstract"  id="abstract" rows=3 class="form-control" placeholder="abstract..."></textarea>
    </div>
```